# Double pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, function, double-pointer

I have the follow prototype:

```
int Split(const char* str, const char* delim,unsigned int& numtokens,char **tokensRes)
```

The last parameter is used to return the response of this function. In the function we have the follow:

```
.
.
char **tokens =(char**) calloc(tokens_alloc, sizeof(char*));
.
.
.
//at the end of the code
tokensRes = tokens;
.
```

When returns the value of tokens variable direct when the return of the function is  `char**`  I receive the correct answer, but using the method above the return of the function came empty. How can I make this function work correctly?

**EDIT 1:**
My intent is receive an array of char arrays, eg:

```
array[0] = "ABC"
array[1] = "ABC"
array[2] = "ABC"
array[3] = "ABC"
```

Comment: I using pointer to pointer because I need a one array of char array

Comment: Do you want to return *string* or *array of strings*?

Comment: remove one `*` in `char **tokens =`, because you're assigning a pointer to a char. Why don't use references?

Comment: Since we don't see the function, It'd be hard to tell you how to correct it. Post a real [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the prototype from:

```
int Split(const char* str, const char* delim,unsigned int& numtokens,char **tokensRes)
```

To:

```
int Split(const char* str, const char* delim,unsigned int& numtokens,char ** &tokensRes)
```

And the code `tokensRes = tokens;` will work. To understand why learn more about C++ and [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

Other answers about using strings are valid if you're planning to move from a C style of coding to a C++ one. The ease of coding would improve a lot and no worries about memory management and pointers (well not often), which are done automatically by classes. No worries about a performance decrease either as long as you follow good practices such as passing objects by reference and not value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return an array of strings (`char**`), then you need to pass a pointer to such an array that you can assign. That is, you need to pass a `char***` and assign it like `*tokensRes = tokens`.

Comment: How do you know this is the intention (a two dimensional array)?  It could merely be a pointer to a pointer that's passed so that the function can set the pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

Just ditch the plain C types and use C++ types:

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(std:;string const& str, std::string const& delim, unsigned int& numtokens);
```

If you have to stick to the C interface, you need an additional indirection with a triple pointer (I am assuming that you want to return an array of token strings).

```
int Split(const char* str, const char* delim,unsigned int& numtokens,char ***tokensRes)

char** tokens;
Split("String;String", ";", 2, &tokens);
```

I really dislike output parameters, and I always wonder why anybody does not use `std::string` in C++.

Tokenizing has been implemented in many libraries, e.g. in [boost::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp398633360) or [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm). No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
// simple_example_1.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<string>

int main(){
   using namespace std;
   using namespace boost;
   string s = "This is,  a test";
   tokenizer<> tok(s);
   for(tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
       cout << *beg << "\n";
   }
}
```

> The output from simple_example_1 is:
>
> ```
> This
> is
> a
> test
> ```

Comment: Or `char **&tokensRes`

Comment: @Hurkyl Yeah, but then we have C++ and could use `vector` and `string`. I wanted to give a plain C answer.